# Error in execution of Triggers with IF condition and DELIMITER in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

Error executing the following code in node with mysql npm.

Coding Language: Node.js

Database: MySQL

NPM: mysql

Query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER db_name.TS_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON db_name.Ticket_Service__c
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.Service_Date_Time__c <> OLD.Service_Date_Time__c || NEW.Status__c <> OLD.Status__c || NEW.Worker__c <> OLD.Worker__c || NEW.Service__c <> OLD.Service__c || NEW.Duration__c <> OLD.Duration__c || NEW.Net_Price__c <> OLD.Net_Price__c || NEW.IsDeleted <> OLD.IsDeleted) THEN
        INSERT INTO db_name.Appointment_History__c SET Appt_Ticket__c = NEW.Appt_Ticket__c, Change__c = JSON_OBJECT('table', 'Ticket_Service__c', 'type', 'UPDATE', 'new', JSON_OBJECT('Service_Date_Time__c', NEW.Service_Date_Time__c, 'Status__c', NEW.Status__c, 'Worker__c', NEW.Worker__c, 'Service__c', NEW.Service__c, 'Duration__c', NEW.Duration__c, 'Net_Price__c', NEW.Net_Price__c, 'IsDeleted', NEW.IsDeleted), 'old', JSON_OBJECT('Service_Date_Time__c', OLD.Service_Date_Time__c, 'Status__c', OLD.Status__c, 'Worker__c', OLD.Worker__c, 'Service__c', OLD.Service__c, 'Duration__c', OLD.Duration__c, 'Net_Price__c', OLD.Net_Price__c, 'IsDeleted', OLD.IsDeleted)), CreatedById = NEW.LastModifiedById, CreatedDate = NEW.LastModifiedDate;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$`

If I execute the query without DELIMITER, like as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER db_name.TS_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON db_name.Ticket_Service__c
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.Service_Date_Time__c <> OLD.Service_Date_Time__c || NEW.Status__c <> OLD.Status__c || NEW.Worker__c <> OLD.Worker__c || NEW.Service__c <> OLD.Service__c || NEW.Duration__c <> OLD.Duration__c || NEW.Net_Price__c <> OLD.Net_Price__c || NEW.IsDeleted <> OLD.IsDeleted) THEN
            INSERT INTO db_name.Appointment_History__c SET Appt_Ticket__c = NEW.Appt_Ticket__c, Change__c = JSON_OBJECT('table', 'Ticket_Service__c', 'type', 'UPDATE', 'new', JSON_OBJECT('Service_Date_Time__c', NEW.Service_Date_Time__c, 'Status__c', NEW.Status__c, 'Worker__c', NEW.Worker__c, 'Service__c', NEW.Service__c, 'Duration__c', NEW.Duration__c, 'Net_Price__c', NEW.Net_Price__c, 'IsDeleted', NEW.IsDeleted), 'old', JSON_OBJECT('Service_Date_Time__c', OLD.Service_Date_Time__c, 'Status__c', OLD.Status__c, 'Worker__c', OLD.Worker__c, 'Service__c', OLD.Service__c, 'Duration__c', OLD.Duration__c, 'Net_Price__c', OLD.Net_Price__c, 'IsDeleted', OLD.IsDeleted)), CreatedById = NEW.LastModifiedById, CreatedDate = NEW.LastModifiedDate;
      END IF;
```

I got the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: In my experience near impossible to get SQL syntax for the mysql adapter correct in javascript/Node. I would look into an ORM instead, like TypeORM, Objection or Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

`DELIMITER` is only recognized by the mysql command-line client. Its only purpose is to help remove the ambiguity between semicolons that are inside the body of a stored routine vs. the semicolon that terminates the whole `CREATE` statement.

Since most programming query APIs do not support multi-query by default, there is no need for `DELIMITER`. Even though the body of your trigger may contain semicolons, the server's SQL parser knows to just keep reading until the last `END`.

So don't use `DELIMITER` if you are executing SQL queries programmatically.

Comment: Thank you Bill. But when I execute the query without delimiter If condition are throwing errors.